# Can a primary key be equal to a different column?

Tags: sql

I know that a primary key must be unique, but is it okay for a primary key to be equal to a different column in the same table by coincidence?

For instance, I have 2 tables. One table is called person that holds information about a person (ID, email, telephone, address, name). The other table is staff (ID, pID(person ID), salary, position). 
In staff the ID column is the primary key and is used to uniquely identify a staff member. The number is from 1 - 100. However, the pID (person ID) may be equal to the ID. For instance the staff ID may be 1 and the pID that it references to may be equal to 1.

Is that okay?

Answer (score 3):

The job of the primary key is to uniquely and reliably identify each row - therefore, it must be unique and `NOT NULL` - anything else is irrelevant.

If you just happen to have a second column with the exact same values - I'd be wondering *why* that is the case - but that doesn't in any way affect the primary key negatively.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There's no checking of relationships between different columns in a table.

The restriction you're worried about doesn't even make sense. Suppose you had a table for persons with columns `ID`, `name`, and `year_of_birth`. It wouldn't allow someone who was born in 1975 to have `ID = 1975`.

Answer (score 1):

Primary key of a table must be unique and not null. There are no restrictions on uniquity between tables. It's 100% up to you.